# Laravel 4: how do I check if a database entry already exists against my store function

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-4

I'm adding posts to a database using a PostsController in Laravel 4

I use a url field in the database to determine what I use for the show post url e.g. url = example-url will mean the post's url will be example.com/example-url

My store function looks like this:

```
public function store()
{
        $input = Input::all();

        $v = Validator::make($input, Post::$rules);

        if($v->passes())
        {
            $this->post->create($input);

            return Redirect::route('cms.index');
        }

        return Redirect::route('cms.create')
            ->withInput()
            ->withErrors($v)
            ->with('message', 'There were validation errors.');
}
```

What is the best way to check if the url entered already exists for another post?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Easy - you want the [Unique validation rule](http://laravel.com/docs/validation#rule-unique)

Add this to your rules

```
array('url' => 'unique:posts'),
```

Comment: Thanks guys, that works - for anyone else stumbling upon this question the rule should go inside the model like this: public static $rules = array( 'url' => 'unique:posts' );

Answer (score 5):

I would check it in validation step.
Add this rule to your validation rules set.
This rules checks for given value in database automaticaly, validation will not pass if same url is found.

```
'url' => 'unique:posts'
```

More info about validation's Unique rule is here http://laravel.com/docs/validation#rule-unique